# Are django abstract models really that useful?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, abstract-class

I have recently come across this in one of django related blog post!

```py
class Client(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
   # .. other fields
   class Meta:
     abstract = True
```

After reading the docs I could  not understand what the purpose of "abstract = True" is.
Any help will be useful. Thanks!

Comment: Typically this is done to inherit from the model, and thus avoiding repeating code.

Comment: Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

> Abstract base classes are useful when you want to put some common
> information into a number of other models. You write your base class
> and put `abstract=True` in the
> [Meta](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#meta-options)
> class. This model will then not be used to create any database table.
> Instead, when it is used as a base class for other models, its fields
> will be added to those of the child class.

Personally I have found that one of many advantages of using abstract models is they allow in software extension and prohibit modifications as per SOLID principles.

Answer (score 4):

An *abstract* model is used to reduce the amount of code, and implement common logic in a reusable component.

For example if you have a lot of models where you want to define two timestamps for `created_at` and `updated_at`, then we can start with a simple abstract model:

```
class UpdatedCreated(models.Model):
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

If we now have three models where we want to include these timestamps we can work with:

```
class Foo(UpdatedCreated):
    other=models.CharField()


class Bar(UpdatedCreated):
    another=models.CharField()


class Qux(UpdatedCreated):
    an_another=models.CharField()
```

now these three models will all have a `created_at` and `updated_at` field. If we define methods on the `UpdatedCreated`, then the models will *inherit* this. We can for example make a field that specifies if the item is still "alive" with:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class UpdatedCreated(models.Model):
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def alive(self):
        return (now() - updated_at).days < 7

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

It is thus a way to easily extend models by the same reusable component.

Answer (score 2):

A database table is not created from the class which has **"abstract=True"** and a child class cannot inherit the fields from the parent class which doesn't have **"abstract=True"**.

For example, **"Student" class** extends **"Person" class** which has **"id"(Hidden), "name" and "age" fields** as shown below:

```py
# "myapp/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   age = models.IntegerField()

class Student(Person):
   pass
```

Then, run this command below:

```
python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
```

Then, **"myapp_person" and "myapp_student" tables** are created from **"Person" and "Student" classes** respectively and because **"Student" class** doesn't inherit **3 fields** from **"Person" class**, **"myapp_student" table** doesn't have them, instead it has **"person_ptr_id"** as shown below:

[image]

Now, add **"abstract = True"** to **"Person" class** as shown below:

```py
# "myapp/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   age = models.IntegerField()

   class Meta:
      abstract = True # Here

class Student(Person):
   pass
```

Then, run this command below:

```
python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
```

Then, only **"myapp_student" table** is created from **"Student" class** and because **"Student" class** inherits **3 fields** from **"Person" class**, **"myapp_student" table** has them as shown below:

[image]